# The logo become pixelated after animating its siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, webkit

I'm working on a project, and its thin header is animated, the animation is: when the user expand the side panel, it takes the half of the screen and the header shrink to the second half.

Now the issue is, when I animate the header to be the half of the screen, the logo become pixelated, and I don't why!

This issue in webkit browsers only [chrome/Safari].

This is a video shows the problem

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9hopzqc4cpdfz6/logo-issue.mkv?dl=0

The HTML

```
<div id="topBar" class="clearfix">
    <a class="logo pull-left" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""/>Three.js Project</a>

    <ul class="topControls clearfix pull-right">
        <li class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>View
            <select name="" id="">
                <option value="">Normal</option>
                <option value="">Back</option>
                <option value="">Inside</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li class="pull-left"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i>Settings</a></li>
        <li class="pull-left"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Save</a></li>
        <li class="pull-left"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i>Calculator</a></li>
        <li class="pull-left"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>Help</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#topBar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 950;
  background: $sceneSectionsBg;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $sceneSectionsBorderColor;

  .logo {
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;

    img {
      margin-right: 7px;
      height: 20px;
    }
  }

  .topControls {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 430px;

    li {
      margin-right: 22px;
      color: lighten($controlsActiveColor, 10%);

      &:last-child {
        margin-right: 15px;
      }

      .fa {
        margin-right: 5px;
      }

      select {
        color: $controlsActiveColor;
        font-size: 12px;
        height: 20px;
        position: relative;
        top: -1px;
        margin-left: 3px;
      }

      a {
        color: lighten($controlsActiveColor, 10%);
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      &:hover a {
        color: lighten($controlsActiveColor, 20%);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The JS

```
$(document).on('click', '#sceneCategoriesToggle', function () {
    var $sceneCategories = $('#sceneCategories'),
        sceneCategoriesWidth = $sceneCategories.outerWidth(),
        isExpanded = $sceneCategories.hasClass('expanded'),
        $relativePanel = $('#bottomPanel, #topBar .topControls');

    if (isExpanded) {
        $sceneCategories.animate({right: -sceneCategoriesWidth}, function () {
            $sceneCategories.removeClass('expanded');
        });
        $relativePanel.animate({right: 0});
        $('.detailsContent .closeBtn').click();
    } else {
        $sceneCategories.animate({right: 0}, function () {
            $sceneCategories.addClass('expanded');
        });

        $relativePanel.animate({right: sceneCategoriesWidth});
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using another small image for the logo, the original image is `200px X 200px`, and the logo is `20px X 20px`, So I used a small image, and this solved the problem.